# Did Jenny "The Doctor's Daughter" feature in any other Doctor Who stories?

Tags: doctor-who

Episode S04E06 of *Doctor Who* -- titled "[The Doctor's Daughter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Daughter)" -- is about a war between two species. During the episode, the Doctor forcefully became the father of a girl named Jenny. Jenny died in the end. The Doctor thought that she could not regenerate and left her to her people. In the end scene, we see that Jenny can indeed regenerate (at least some sort of regeneration; she didn't change in appearance). She stole a shuttle and flew away to experience adventures. Jenny was never mentioned again the series.

Is there a comic, side show or audiobook about Jenny, or was it just a hint in a story arc which was never really explored outside of that one episode?

Comment: There's a fairly comprehensive list of her ongoing appearances here; https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Jenny

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened to the Doctor's daughter after the Doctor Who episode “The Doctor's Daughter”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/what-happened-to-the-doctors-daughter-after-the-doctor-who-episode-the-doctor)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing This question includes non-show appearances, like the ones in the answer, so it can't really be answered on the other question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Big Finish did two audio book series about The Doctor's Daughter, voiced by Georgia Tennant (the original actor for Jenny, and IRL the fifth Doctor's daughter and the tenth Doctor's wife).

https://www.bigfinish.com/releases/v/jenny-the-doctor-s-daughter-series-01-1701

https://www.bigfinish.com/releases/v/jenny-the-doctor-s-daughter-series-02-still-running-2436

> Jenny is brand new to the universe. Born a soldier, made for war, she
> has a Time Lord's heritage. Luckily, that Time Lord is the Doctor.
> She's ready to save planets, fight monsters, and save the day, using
> nothing but her bravery, wit and instinct - and an awful lot of
> running.

She has appeared as a side character in several of the Doctor's comics, but not to my knowledge as a main character. The Tardis Fandom wiki uses her panel for their entry in The Lost Dimension cross-over series.

https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lost_Dimension_(comic_story)